# Can't use a neon JsArray: This function takes 3 parameters but 2 were supplied

Tags: rust, node.js-addon

I'm learning how to use neon, but I don't understand a thing. If I try to execute this code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate neon;
use neon::vm::{Call, JsResult};
use neon::mem::Handle;
use neon::js::{JsInteger, JsNumber, JsString, JsObject, JsArray, JsValue, Object, Key};
use neon::js::error::{JsError, Kind};

fn test(call: Call) -> JsResult<JsArray> {
    let scope = call.scope;
    let js_arr: Handle<JsArray> = try!(try!(call.arguments.require(scope, 1)).check::<JsArray>());

    js_arr.set(0, JsNumber::new(scope, 1000));

    Ok(js_arr)
}

register_module!(m, {
    m.export("test", test)
});
```

I get this error when I call `js_arr.set`: `This function takes 3 parameters but 2 were supplied.`

I don't understand why since it's a `JsArray`. Even Racer tells me that the set method takes 2 parameters. No matter what, `js_arr.set` takes 3 parameters in this order: `&mut bool`, `neon::macro_internal::runtime::raw::Local` and `neon::macro_internal::runtime::raw::Local`.

What's happening? I can't understand how `JsArray` works.

Comment: I see that you [opened an issue in the neon repository](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon/issues/218) — did you also read the [existing issue about `JsArray`](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon/issues/57)?

Comment: @Shepmaster Found the way, sorry if i've been rude, thanks for helping.

Comment: No worries; I totally understand how trying struggling to pick up a new language or library can be frustrating! The good news is that it looks like a bunch of other people have had the same underlying problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [paulsevere says on a GitHub issue for Neon](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon/issues/57#issuecomment-310842980), import `neon::js::Object`. In addition, do **not** import `Key`, which also provides a `set` method:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate neon;

use neon::vm::{Call, JsResult};
use neon::js::{Object, JsArray, JsInteger, JsObject, JsNumber};

fn make_an_array(call: Call) -> JsResult<JsArray> {
    let scope = call.scope; // the current scope for rooting handles
    let array = JsArray::new(scope, 3);
    array.set(0, JsInteger::new(scope, 9000))?;
    array.set(1, JsObject::new(scope))?;
    array.set(2, JsNumber::new(scope, 3.14159))?;
    Ok(array)
}

register_module!(m, {
    m.export("main", make_an_array)
});
```

This creates a brand new array. If you'd like to accept an array as the first argument to your function and then modify it, this works:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate neon;

use neon::vm::{Call, JsResult};
use neon::js::{Object, JsArray, JsInteger, JsUndefined};
use neon::mem::Handle;

fn hello(call: Call) -> JsResult<JsUndefined> {
    let scope = call.scope;
    let js_arr: Handle<JsArray> = call.arguments.require(scope, 0)?.check::<JsArray>()?;

    js_arr.set(0, JsInteger::new(scope, 1000))?;

    Ok(JsUndefined::new())
}

register_module!(m, {
    m.export("hello", hello)
});
```

Comment: @pietrovismara *I already imported `JsObject`* — not the **type** `JsObject`, the **trait** `Object`. There's a difference, which would explain why it didn't work.

Comment: That's true (typo), but if you look at my question, you can see that i also imported `Object`. I guess maybe the order of the import or something else made the difference?

Comment: @pietrovismara ah, figured it out; it's about `Key` — that adds another method called `set` that causes the problem.

Comment: really interesting, i didn't know that methods could be overridden like this. So much to learn about Rust yet!

Answer (score 1):

`let js_arr: Handle<JsArray>` makes it clear that `js_arr` is a `Handle<JsArray>` and [`Handle<T>`](https://api.neon-bindings.com/neon/mem/struct.handle) has this method:

```
unsafe fn set(self, out: &mut bool, obj: Local, val: Local) -> bool
```

I'd guess that you're accidentally trying to call [`Handle::set`](https://api.neon-bindings.com/neon/mem/struct.handle#set.v) (which is `unsafe` and takes three non-`self` arguments) rather than [`JsArray::set`](https://api.neon-bindings.com/neon/js/struct.jsarray#set.v) (which is safe and takes two non-`self` arguments).

If that's the case, you need to force a [`deref_mut`](https://api.neon-bindings.com/neon/mem/struct.handle#deref_mut.v) to occur. (`_mut` because `JsArray::set` takes `&mut self`.)

I haven't run into this sort of naming collision before, so I can't be certain whether the [auto-deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html) is smart enough, but something like this may work:

```
(&mut js_arr).set(0, JsNumber::new(scope, 1000));
```

Failing that, two other things to try are:

1. `JsArray::set(&mut js_arr, 0, JsNumber::new(scope, 1000));`

   (If the former example fails because it's too much like C++-style method overloading. This is known as [Fully Qualified Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation) and is normally used to disambiguate when an object implements two traits which provide methods of the same name.)
2. Call [`js_arr.deref_mut()`](https://api.neon-bindings.com/neon/mem/struct.handle#deref_mut.v) directly to get a mutable reference to the underlying `JsArray`, then call `set` on that.

Comment: *something like this may work* — why not try it out instead of guessing?

Comment: @Shepmaster Neon isn't part of the Rust Playground and I don't have time to muddle my way through setting up a test environment on my own machine right now. (I've never used Node.js beyond `npm install -g`. If it were a `rust-cpython` question, I could just slap a line into one of my existing projects for a quick test.)

Comment: You don't have to set anything up. It's dynamically linked, so you can get the Rust code to compile and then it will just fail to link later.

Comment: I tested your solutions and found the last one working, but i still have a problem. Could you look at my edit?

Comment: @Shepmaster at least ssokolow is trying to help. Can't tell the same for you.

Comment: Note that [`set`](https://api.neon-bindings.com/neon/js/trait.object#method.set) takes self by value.

Comment: @pietrovismara I'm sorry that that's the impression I've left. My primary goal is not to help any *one* person, but to push questions and answers to be the best they can be for **everyone** who comes later. That's the point of Stack Overflow - to be a repository of information so we never need to answer the same question twice. An "answer" that says "this may work" doesn't help those who come afterwards. A question with content that doesn't match the title will never be found by those who need it.